# Verification exception : Unexpected

Tags: litecoin, java, android

i have cloned litecoin wallet and edit it connect to the network we have created. I disabled checkoints, changed params and the block syncs for 32 blocks. Then i get the following error

```
05-26 13:07:41.876  7339  7381 W Peercom.google.bitcoin.core.VerificationException: Could not verify block a2ba184558d58648ecedCaused by: com.google.bitcoin.core.VerificationException: Unexpected change in difficulty at height 31: 1e0fd5e6 vs 1e10024c
```

Any ideas? The interval is indeed 16 blocks. Thanks!

Comment: Well, seems i had an error at Network parameters. Now it is resolved!